# Web Application not able to connect to db

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, web, deployment

### Stack Trace:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file
>   specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to
>   locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server
>   Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime
>   feature is enabled.)]

I have deployed my database to the server using ssms 2016, and added the connection string to my web application that is deployed.However I received the following error message posted above.I suspected that the application cannot reach the database.

I tried changing the connection string several times to no avail

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few times and this is what i did:
go to "services" in your computer. try to find sql server  from the whole list and see if the program is running. If it doesn't say "running" , then just select it and go to the top and press on the green arrow and it will start to run again.